# How to pass a value through URL_path and retrieve it in targeted page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a rails application, where I am adding players to the team, I need to send a model id through link_to url_path, but I don't know how to do it, I tried with the following code.

//new.html.erb
f is a looping variable

```
   <td><%= link_to 'Add player', new_player_path(f.id)   %></td>
```

//controller

```
def new
        @team = Team.find(params[:id])

    end
```

//targeted page

```
<h3>Add players to team <% @team.team_name %></h3>
```

Comment: try `new_player_path(id: f.id)`, but if you want meaningful names, I'd rather use `new_player_path(team_id: f.id)` and change the code in your controller to `@team = Team.find(params[:team_id])`

Comment: its is giving an error like Couldn't find Team without an ID

Comment: are you using `new_player_path(team_id: f.id)` and `@team = Team.find(params[:team_id])` ?. Look at your rails console and see if `team_id` param is being sent, you can also set a `binding.pry` in your `new` method and inspect the params sent.

Comment: thank you it worked